# centering placeholder in the same UITextField, but of two different sizes

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I am trying to have the same placeholder text centered in two different sizes of the same `UITextField`.

The `UITextField` in question is 243 wide in Portrait and 360 in Landscape.

When in Portrait the placeholder centers in the middle just fine. When I rotate to Landscape and the `UITextField` gets redrawn bigger, it is no longer centered. It's like 25% to the left (I am guessing in the middle of the Portrait length)

Is there any way to re-center the placeholder every time the length of a `UITextField` changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interesting. 5 minutes after I posted this question an idea came to mind.

After the textfield gets redrawn in Portrait I do this:

```
Textfield.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
Textfield.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

After the textfield gets redrawn in Landscape I do this:

```
Textfield.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
Textfield.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Now the placeholder is perfectly centered in both modes. Hacky, but seems to work. Until someone replies with the "proper way", I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably accomplish the same result with:

```
[textfield setNeedsLayout];
```

or, possibly

```
[textfield setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: I tried each, but neither fixed the mis-centered placeholder ... also tried them back to back. thanks for the input regardless.